# AT+CSQ report at LTE network

Tags: gsm, at-command, lte, umts

Is AT+CSQ RSSI interpretation the same for LTE as for GSM and UMTS? I can't seem to find any solid info on the Internet.

My AT+CSQ returns RSSI and BER. BER always seems to be 99, and RSSI differs between 0 and 31 for GSM, and between seemingly 0 and 21 for LTE. I mean, I haven't seen any better reports even as I live directly under the LTE BTS for the cell.

I'm using Cinterion's ELS61.

Answer (score 1):

The AT+CSQ command helps in measuring Signal to Noise Ratio which inturn can help in determining the relative quality of the received signal. In general, CSQ is between 0 and 31 and scaling method or mapping to RSSI is specific to cellular technology (LTE or GSM or CDMA)

Comment: I know that, but this doesn't help me at all. Does 0-31 in GSM mean the same in 0-31 LTE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have the same doubt, but here's the answer:

According to "ELS61-E2 AT Command Specification", the RSSI value is not compatible with 3G networks, therefore, you should use the AT "AT^SMONI" to acquire that information.

Nevertheless, other types of the network should be included in the AT+CSQ command, and have the same interpretation. Working with Telit modules, that have a similar AT datasheet, we also consider that the RSSI value is equally readable to every network type, but the  value is interpreted differently as the network changes.